# code logical error in SML

Tags: smlnj

I'm using the below code for square root from a cornell course, however the code returns wrong values, The code is

```
fun squareRoot(x: real): real =
  let
    val delta = 0.0001
    fun goodEnough(guess: real): bool =
      if(abs(guess*guess - x) < delta) then true else false
    fun improve(guess: real): real =
      (guess + x/guess) / 2.0
    fun tryGuess(guess: real): real =
      if goodEnough(guess) then guess
      else tryGuess(improve(guess))
  in
    tryGuess(1.0)
  end
```

When executing

```
 use "squareroot1.sml";
[opening squareroot1.sml]
val squareRoot = fn : real -> real
val it = () : unit
- squareroot 9.0;
val it = 1.0 : real
-
```

It always returns 1.0 as the root can you please tell why this is happening?

Comment: I get `val it = 3.0000000014 : real` with that code. Did you forget to save, or load the wrong file?

Comment: Nope same file.....is something wrong with my SMLNJ installation?

Comment: Try to enter the code directly into the interpreter instead of using "use" and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo when you call the function, you need to change the `squareroot` to `squareRoot`.